# How to exclude broadcasts from search by video results?

Tags: google-api, youtube-api, youtube-data-api

In docs (https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/search/list) I've only found options that allow me to include only translations with the specified status (completed / live / upcoming) in my search results, but I have the reverse task - to exclude all translations from the search results. How to do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution:
params.eventType = 'completed'

Comment: I'm glad you found the answer. Just curious, can you share in your question the URL API request you tried? - I though that by just adding the `type` parameter value to `video` was enough, but, again, I'm curious about which search you're trying...

Answer (score 0):

The [videos.search](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/search/list) method dos not have an option exclude broadcasts from search by video results.

You will need to do this yourself after you have downloaded the results

You may want to consider adding this as a [feature request](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/new?component=186600&template=874803)